# rewritemod для .htacces

Tags: .htaccess

На сайте есть админ панель вида `site.ru/adp/admpanel.php`, там же и окно авторизации `site.ru/adp/admlogin.php`
Знаю что RewriteMod в файле htaccess можно поменять имя в строке, но везде примеры именно с заменой самого файла.
А можно ли сделать так, чтобы файл `admlogin.php` открывался при вводе в браузере `site.ru/adp/`

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^adp$ /adm/admlogin.php
```

Рекомендую ознакомиться со статьёй: [Введение в использование mod_rewrite](https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=29&id=740). Изложено всё вполне доступно! ;)